# Passing events as parameters in typescript failing because of type errors in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, addeventlistener, event-listener, react-typescript

I am trying to pass this event through to my event listener in my type script file however the event listener won't allow any other Event types to be passed through except Event, MouseEvent and a few others.

```
public componentDidMount() {
    const app = document.querySelector(".app");
    app.addEventListener("click", ((event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
      this._handleWhiteSpaceEvent(event);
    }) as EventListener);
  }
```

The event listener keeps throwing up the error
`Conversion of type '(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' to type 'EventListener' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible`
Or when I try a React.MouseEvent
`Conversion of type '(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' to type 'EventListener' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.`

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Attach the listener with the JSX instead - avoid `addEventListener` in React

Comment: i need to use an an event listener however tho otherwise yes i would be using the another way

Answer (score 0):

When you set an event listener directly on an element like `app` then the event that you get is **not** a `React.SyntheticEvent`.  It's just a regular `MouseEvent` from the `lib.dom.ts` definitions.  You get a synthetic event when setting the `onClick` property on a DOM node.

You need to make sure that you have a valid `app` element and not `null` since `document.querySelector` is not guaranteed to find a result.

You can get an `Event` just with optional chaining.

```
app?.addEventListener("click", (event: Event) => {
  this._handleWhiteSpaceEvent(event);
});
```

In order to use the `MouseEvent` type, you must refine the type of `app` from `Element` to `HTMLElement`.

```
if (app instanceof HTMLElement) {
  app.addEventListener("click", (event: MouseEvent) => {
    this._handleWhiteSpaceEvent(event);
  });
}
```

Neither of these types are generic the way that the React event types are.  You get far more information with less checks by setting your event listeners through JSX.